# How to export to excel from a dashlet?

Tags: export

I can't remember how to add the `excel` button at the bottom of a dashlet. I'm pretty sure I had it previously but I can't find any more how and where to set it back.

I have the CiviCRM Export to Excel extension installed and now I need to export directly from the dashlet.

Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searchkit + Form builder do perfectly the job! An upgrade to 5.44 was the solution (previous recent version are also enough)